# Laravel - Exclude the row from the logged in user when validating unique

Tags: database, laravel

How can i exclude the row from the logged in user when validating something that must be unique (except the row from the user itself)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the logged in user's id in validation rule - `unique` like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'unique:users,email,' . auth()->id,
]);
// This will validate unique email in users table except the column referenced to the logged in user id.
```

> `unique:table_name,column_name,except,idColumn`
>
> See more about [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique) rule

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ive got this now
    `'xbgt'     => 'max:20|unique:users,xbgt,' . auth()->xbgt,`

But i get this error:

**Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$xbgt**

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear. If you are talking about something like user profile update (when user has to have unique email, but his email is already in DB) you should read this from the docs:

> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check. For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address.
>
> To instruct the validator to ignore the user's ID, we'll use the Rule class to fluently define the rule. In this example, we'll also specify the validation rules as an array instead of using the | character to delimit the rules:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Ive got this now 'xbgt' => 'max:20|unique:users,xbgt,' . auth()->xbgt, But i get this error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$xbgt

Comment: This is the code from another answer. I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with this way to validate unique field. Did you try the official way (code from docs which I've posted in my answer)?

Comment: @Robinvm no, you couldn't get same error with my code. This error occurs because of `auth()->xbgt` part which is used only in the code from another answer. Error simply means that there is no `xbgt` property. You may try to use `auth()->user()->xbgt` if you want to use `xbgt` property of authenticated user. But I'd recommend you to use the official way anyway.

Comment: I did your original anwser, now it gives this error:

    ErrorException in Factory.php line 91:
    Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of             the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 237 and defined